# Running script.exe gives PermissionError: [Errno 13] , but running the same code in script.py doesn't

Tags: python

I have a Python script that modifies an Excel file. It works fine.

When I turn that same script into an executable, and try to run it, it gives me an error saying it can't modify the Excel file.

[image]

I don't understand why. I run the .exe as an admin. The Excel file is not read-only and can be modified by admins. Any help would be appreciated.

The line that gives the error is  `wb.save('mybots.xlsx')`

```
def myClick():

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"mybots.xlsx")
    sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

    # loop through the list of checkboxes and write their value to excel
    idx = 0
    while idx < list_length:
        cb = list_checkboxes[idx]
        varname = cb.cget("variable")
        cbValue = root.getvar(varname)
        sheet.cell(row=idx+2, column=2).value = str(cbValue)
        idx += 1
        wb.save('mybots.xlsx')
```

Comment: I'm going to be the guy that asks the silly question: are you sure you don't have the Excel file open elsewhere while running the executable?

Comment: No no no, I checked :)

Comment: Where are you saving to? If you're saving to somewhere in `C:\Program Files` or something like that, it might be a directory permissions issue, rather than a file overwrite issue

Comment: No, it's all in the same folder on desktop. It's the same directory where running a .py works fine.

Comment: Are you using `zipfile` for something (why do I see it in the traceback)? Are you able to reproduce the error without using zipfile?

Comment: I'm not using zip for anything and don't know why it's in the traceback tbh. Could it be automatically used when I use the pyinstaller.exe --onefile to make the executable?

Comment: I think there are two problems here, then

Comment: Ehh what are they? I really can't find anything online why my callback would have zipfile.py in it

Comment: Mind including the line that triggers this?

Comment: Added the line that triggers it. It's the line that saves changes to the excel file. However, as I said, when I just run the script with the same code (.py, not .exe), it saves the changes perfectly.

Comment: (Some types of) Excel files are zip files internally so presumably `openpyxl` is using `zipfile` internally to support that. @inspectorG4dget is probably offering a red herring.